# how do i detect when a folder or file is accessed in java?

Tags: java

I'm an Italian student with the passion of programming and I'm creating an application that asks the user to insert a password when opening a precedently specified file or folder. My problem is how to detect when the user opens the file/folder using an event, if possible. Can you help me please?

Comment: In my opinion, that is a very weak security system... The only way to guarantee that a user cannot access file content without entering a password is using encryption.

Comment: @CommuSoft Thanks for your opinion. But you can only with third party libraries not acutally something you would go ahead and code

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of Java WatchService Api and register all the events that you want to listen to. Here is the official tutorial from Oracle : [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)